# JSON to HTML CSS output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a registration form, on `data.error` PHP outputs as JSON the errors
`exit('{"error": "Passwords do not match!"}');`

After a successful register, the user will be redirected to `exit('{"location": "home.php"}');`

I want the json output, instead of plain text to be put into html+css for styling,
so i can style div for the errors

```js
            document
                    .querySelector(".register form")
                    .addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const form = e.target;
                        const body = new FormData(form);
                        const res = await fetch(form.action, {
                            method: "POST",
                            body,
                        });
                        const data = await res.json();
                        if (data.error) { // If there is an error
                            document.querySelector("#msg").innerHTML = data.error; 

                        }
                        else if (data.location) { // If we want to redirect the user somewhere
                            window.location.href = "./" + data.location;
                        }
                    });
```

If i add a class,
`<div id="msg" class="error"></div>` doesn't output anything,
while only inline style `style="background-color:red;">` will work

```css
.error {
    background: #F2DEDE;
    color: #A94442;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

}
```

[image]

I been researching this for 12 hours, i've seen few examples about `JSON.stringify` and others,
but i don't know how could i implement this into my code

Comment: Simply wrap what you're returning in html tags. ```exit('{"error": "<div class="error">Passwords do not match!</div>"}');``` or style the element with id ```msg```. I really don't see where is the problem

Comment: edit: i did ```<div class="msg" style="background-color:red;"></div>``` and worked.

Comment: Well, probably I don't get what you want to achieve. What do you mean by it will still do plaintext?

Comment: for some reason only inline css will work within the div tag, (for the json) if i try to take from style.css it won't output (while the file is correct)

Comment: Check my answer. May be that's what you want

Comment: ```<div id="msg" class="error"></div>``` doesn't output anything, while inline style ```style="background-color:red;">``` will work

Comment: What style are you applying for class error? If you have a white background and color is also white, what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Oh font hex is red and background is white, when i either add class or try with classList.add, it won't output any text at all. (nothing shows in console) Only inline styling will work for some reason

Comment: You're confusing yourself. That class is added dynamically as per my answer. And with the style provided everything should work correctly. I have the same on my login page and I'm not using any inline style

Comment: Can you add your html and css here?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TGfURvv6

Comment: Can you see the placeholder text in the proper style when you haven't submitted the form ? 
`some error inside div, try with json`

Comment: You didn't follow what I posted in my answer at all. The class error has not to be manually added, instead it is added by JavaScript  when an error is returned from your backend

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if this is the correct way to return your data as JSON. You normally only do ```echo json_encode($data); ```

Answer (score 1):

Well I still don't know if I understand your case correctly. You can add a class to element msg for when an error is returned.

```
if (data.error) { // If there is an error
document.querySelector("#msg").classList.add("error"); //This will be styled from your CSS. Add a background, etc
document.querySelector("#msg").innerHTML = data.error;
}
```

CSS:

```
.error {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: For some reason it won't output the text with the  added line

Comment: HUM! I don't know what style you're applying. Kindly update your question with relevant infos.

Answer (score 0):

```
function login($username, $password) {
  // do a login

  // if any errors
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;

  // or if you're using any framework/controller then return properly
  // using a json response containing the error i.e. "Invalid Login"
}
```

You want to do something like that server side.  Then on the client side you want to get the response, check if there are errors and display the errors if they exist.  Use a visible class or something for that so that you can change the visibility and display errors.  So you create the div and css the way you want to and just use `display: none` on it, then if you do get errors you make it visible.

Don't use PHP to generate HTML/CSS, especially not in this way, unless you're using a proper view engine, otherwise you'll end up creating a mess.  Send back a proper JSON response and do your UI stuff client side based on that response.